# Setting up a jailed, session-resetting, Windows thin client server

Tags: thin-client

This is probably out there somewhere (what isn't?), but I don't even know what to call it for searching purposes.

Here's what I think I want... there may be a better way to do it, I am open to suggestions. I want to set up a Windows server for a business. The server will have all the required software installed (QuickBooks, desktop publishing, word processor, etc.). Instead of installing it all on separate machines, I want thin client-like stations that opens a session on the server and allows controlled access to the programs and shared files.

By "controlled", I mean they can install VLC (for example) to play an odd-format video from an e-mail, but that installation is "jailed" in a temporary container that gets removed upon session logoff.

Similar to Windows SteadyState functionality by allowing a remote user to do whatever they need up to and including software installation, but then it rolls back to a pre-determined state and the server is not practically affected in any way. But only for a session, not the whole server.

There are two reasons I want this. Like most computer users, the employees are not tech-savvy and will end up installing junkware, malware, bloatware, and other undesirable 'wares' by installing a free photo viewer, for example (they didn't need the viewer in the first place but they didn't know that). I could have spent hours the other day uninstalling junk that accumulated on one of their computers. We've all seen it happen. Performance suffers. Complaints begin.

The second reason is obvious: manageability. Much like deployed software on a Windows Domain environment.

Suggestions? Questions? (I'm sure there will be clarification needed on this!)

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but be sure to take into account Windows CAL's and licensing in general into you're business model.

Comment: Why not use Remote Desktop Services and install the software the users need. Use standard user accounts for the end users so that they can't install software on the servers themselves.

Comment: @SqlACID: that has been discussed. The software packages the businesses uses is licensed for multiple users so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @joeqwerty: I've thought of that, but the problem is the user may indeed need to install a legitimate piece of software temporarily. I want them to have that ability, but: 1) I need it gone when they log out (keep it clean), and 2) I can't have the program installing services on the server that stay running in the background (performance issues, etc.).